# DeepSpeed Optimizer Problems

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to use the deepspeed optimizer to allow me to fit more into memory and speed up my training. I keep having this trouble with the optimizer and I am not sure what is causing it. The error is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "02232022_kat_repr_train.py", line 89, in <module>
    first_exp.run_experiment()
  File "experiments.py", line 28, in run_experiment
    self.trainer.train(self.hyperparameters["epochs"], self.hyperparameters["eval_period"])
  File "trainer.py", line 90, in train
    self.optimizer.step()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/mmlm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/zero/stage_1_and_2.py", line 1633, in step
    self.check_overflow()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/mmlm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/zero/stage_1_and_2.py", line 1913, in check_overflow
    self._check_overflow(partition_gradients)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/mmlm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/zero/stage_1_and_2.py", line 1818, in _check_overflow
    self.overflow = self.has_overflow(partition_gradients)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/mmlm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/zero/stage_1_and_2.py", line 1837, in has_overflow
    overflow = self.local_overflow if self.cpu_offload else self.has_overflow_partitioned_grads_serial(
  File "/anaconda3/envs/mmlm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/zero/stage_1_and_2.py", line 1830, in has_overflow_partitioned_grads_serial
    for j, grad in enumerate(self.averaged_gradients[i]):
KeyError: 0
```

My training code is pretty standard:

```
outputs = self.model(**batch)
loss = self.loss_function(outputs)
loss = self.loss_aggregation(loss)
epoch_loss += loss
loss.backward()
self.optimizer.backward(loss)
self.model.zero_grad()
```

I initialize deepspeed like this: `self.model, self.optimizer, _, self.lr_scheduler = ds.initialize(model=self.model, config_params=self.deepspeed_config, optimizer=self.optimizer, lr_scheduler=self.lr_scheduler)`

I am using the example configurations from here: https://github.com/microsoft/DeepSpeedExamples/blob/master/Megatron-LM/scripts/ds_zero2_config.json

Does anyone know why I am getting this issue?

Thank you!